# Heroku, multiple heroku apps in same directory, how to remove all but one?

Tags: git, heroku

I've accidentally created multiple heroku apps in my git repo:

```
(workout) n155-p250:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ heroku create agile-garden-20427
Creating ⬢ agile-garden-20427... done
(workout) n155-p250:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ heroku create
Creating app... done, ⬢ immense-harbor-64484
(workout) n155-p250:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ heroku create workoutcalendar
Creating ⬢ workoutcalendar... done
```

I only want one heroku app, the one named workoutcalendar. So I went online to remove all other apps from my heroku account. I went into the app settings and clicked delete app, for each app except workoutcalendar. Yet, when I try to `push`, it still remembers an old app, that I've removed.

```
(workout) n155-p250:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ git push heroku master
remote: !   No such app as agile-garden-20427.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-garden-20427.git/' not found
```

My guess is that the `git push heroku master` command somehow maps to the first heroku app I created, and that I have to change this on my own machine, in the local repo. I'd be ever so grateful if someone could explain how to do this to me, or, if I'v misunderstood the issue, provide a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your `git remote -v` output: if it still refers the wrong URL, you can change it with:

```
git remote set-url origin https://git.heroku.com/workoutcalendar.git
```

Then try and push again.